# Can you have static leases without DHCP?

Tags: dhcp, static-ip, dhcp-server, dynamic-ip

Is it possible to assign IPs to only those on a static lease list, but not give dynamic IPs to unknown MACs? It seems DHCP is required to have a static lease list?

Comment: Please make your comment an answer and I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, make your dhcp pool have 0 addresses but leave the static list. Most enterprise equipment and servers allow for this. Standard SOHO routers generally do not let you have no dhcp range when dhcp is enabled, although you can often set the range to 1 IP address and have everything else assigned by static DHCP.

The exact process varies by manufacturer and system.

Comment: A friend was showing me how it worked on DD-WRT. So, port 67 & 68 needs to be available. Do you know if access to DNS server is required for DHCP to work?